# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax (no last line commas)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am exporting my localhost db so I can upload it to a website host.

Upon importing on the website host I get this error:

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `achievements` (

 `no` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'delete me though',
 `MyID` INT( 5 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS  `my id:` ,
 `MyAch` INT( 5 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS  `my achievement` ,
 `Date` VARCHAR( 11 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS  `awarded on:` ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `no` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =45 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `my id:`,
  `MyAch` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS `my achievement`,
  `Date`' at line 3
```

This is the area it is talking about:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `achievements`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `achievements` (
  `no` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'delete me though',
  `MyID` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS `my id:`,
  `MyAch` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS `my achievement`,
  `Date` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT AS `awarded on:`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

All the other questions mention having a comma on the last line, but I dont have have that.

Do you know what is wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the back ticks around your comments to single quotes
2. Change instances of `COMMENT AS` to `COMMENT`

You should be able to execute the following directly in the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin without errors:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `achievements`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `achievements` (
  `no` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'delete me though',
  `MyID` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'my id:',
  `MyAch` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'my achievement',
  `Date` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'awarded on:',
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If that works, but you still encounter the issue after exporting/importing, then the problem may be a bug in the version of phpMyAdmin being used on your local server or the webhost. For example, see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12076, in which incorrect syntax is introduced into exported files using `DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: Thank you this is working :) I'm having to do this through the whole sql.